# Is there any way to find the no of active connections to a database without using SQL queries?

Tags: java, database, database-connection, connection-pooling

I want it programmatically (JAVA or any other frameworks of java) to find the no of active connections to a database but there shouldn't be any SQL queries used.
Using SQL queries in java program i found the no of active connections, but i don't want it through queries. If there's any other method please let me know.
Actually i created a connection pool using BasicDataSource but the getNumActive() method shows only the connections made through the app but doesn't give the no of connections made to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Only the database knows the number of active connections. You can't get it without asking the database.

Comment: @rajadilipkolli nothing "humours" about this. Only the database server knows about the connections it has (and a lot more), so the only way to get the information is to ask the server, which is done (atleast in most databases) by querying. Of course the server can provide other ways to offer that information, but that would just be additional complexity.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you just tell me the other ways through which i can get thst information. I mean, lets say i have made a connection to the database usinf a java program. So after making connection can i retrieve the no of active connections using some java methods.

Comment: @SatishSaini No, you will have to use database specific queries to find that out.